# Calling a method in a java web service, with an object as parameter, from c# client

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, soap-client

I have written a web service in java with axis2 and tomcat, and also a client in c# which I have successfully called methods on the web server with.
But I am struggling with a method, which has to be able to take in any Object as a parameter. A float, string, random file or picture.

I tried making a serializable object in c#, which I can create and put my String inside and then send it as a parameter to my web service funtion.
But I get: Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Xml.dll

How should I solve this? I guess I have to serialize it first, but I dont get how I do that and then send the serialized object as a parameter to the function. And does this object have to be defined on the web service too?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to run into problems if you want to send "any" C# object to Java. C# objects do not easily reduce to a Java object.  They are different languages and each have some unique features in their object model.  Instead, find an language neutral format (like Json) that can capture whatever type of data you need.  Common data formats like Int, String, Boolean, etc are easily captured in JSon.  More complex objects can be created as well with JSON.

So, I recommend the following.  For each C# object you want to send across the wire, have it implement a toJson method, which takes it state and dumps it into JSON, transmit the JSON and deserilize as a Java Object.  This should cover most cases.

Comment: I guess this is equivalent to making an xml out of the object instead?

Comment: This is kind of what I wanted to try, but I wasn't really sure how to make the make the xml and pass it to the function from the C# client.

Comment: You don't need xml just Json .  First make sure you know how to deal with Json in c# and Java,  with out worrying about web stuff.  Then learn how to send that Json string across the wire

Comment: U could use xml but most people find xml more burdensome to deal with